# How to programmatically check if a email is registered in the Telegram?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to build a telegram bot. In that I need to know if anyone is registered with a email address. I checked the documentation but didn't found any answer. If it is possible with telegram core api please feel free to answer.

Comment: I don't believe you can. It is my understanding that the bots can only access (certain) information about users that message the bot. Otherwise, I'm sure there would be a lot of privacy complaints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no possibility to register in Telegram using anything else except phone number.

You can **NOT** use email, social auth or any other kind of tokens.

Only phone number.